# Drupal: make a text field collapsible

Tags: jquery, drupal

Fieldsets in Drupal are collapsible. Is there a simple way to re-cycle this kind of functionality to a text field in a content type?

A text field is typically rendered as

```
 <div class="field field-type-text field-field-my-field">
     <div class="field-label"> My field Label: </div>
     <div class="field-items">
            ....
     </div>
 </div>
```

Like with a field set, how would one make the `field-label` clickable to collapse and expand the `field-items`?

My current avenue of attack is to add the `collapsed` css class with jQuery when the page is rendered, but am wondering if this kind of thing is already available somehow in the Drupal framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was easier than I thought:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".field-field-mytextfield .field-items").css('display','none');
      $(".field-field-mytextfield .field-label").click ( function () 
          { 
            $(this).parent().children( ".field-items").slideToggle('slow');
         } );
});
```

Comment: +1: There's no way to do it via the form API, so you would have to use CSS/JS.